# Reset to default browser size

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

I accidentally resized tor browser.

How to change back to default size without restart?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Linux you can use `wmctrl`. You may need to install it first. You can use a command like:

`wmctrl -r Tor -e 0,0,0,1000,600`

See `man wmctrl` for more on how to use it. In the example, "Tor" is a substring that should find and isolate your window (unless it appears in more than one). `1000,600` appears to be the default window geometry, but may vary based on platform and screen resolution.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is opening a new plain window, e.g. using `Ctrl`+`N`.

Then, you can place the old window above the new one in one corner and resize it to fit the corner on the other side. This is very easy with "sticky" window borders (configurable depending on the used desktop environment).

Afterwards, you can close the plain window again.